# mongodb 3.4.2 InvalidIndexSpecificationOption error: The field 'unique' is not valid for an _id index specification

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-indexes

The command `db.testCollection.createIndex( { _id: 1 }, {name: "_id_2", unique: true, background: true} )` fails on mongo version 3.4.2, but not 3.2.11.  The mongo documentation indicates the version 3.4 supports both the `unique` and `background` attributes.

Mongo 3.4.2 fails ...

```
> use testDB
switched to db testDB
> db.testCollection.createIndex( { _id: 1 }, {name: "_id_2", unique: true, background: true} )
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The field 'unique' is not valid for an _id index specification. Specification: { ns: \"testDB.testCollection\", v: 1, key: { _id: 1.0 }, name: \"_id_2\", unique: true, background: true }",
    "code" : 197,
    "codeName" : "InvalidIndexSpecificationOption"
}
>
```

Mongo 3.2.11 works ...

```
> use testDB
switched to db testDB
> db.testCollection.createIndex( { _id: 1 }, {name: "_id_2", unique: true, background: true} )
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 1,
    "note" : "all indexes already exist",
    "ok" : 1
}
>
```

Anyone know of a work around?

We're using the Mongoose Node.js wrapper to create the Mongo indexes, so not adding the `unique` and `background` attributes isn't an option.

Cheers!

Ed

Comment: how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 12):

That unique is not problem here.. It's that _id, what already have index (created automatically) and you **cannot** create second index what have exactly same fields (_id:1) what first one have.

How about testing with some other field than _id and you will find out that unique and background is possible, as long as that field don't have index already present.

Comment: Thanks J.Jussi, that's it.  I didn't grok the note from 3.2.11 which was pointing out the redundant indexing request.  So obvious now that you've pointed it out.

Comment: @JJussi - what would you suggest for the index { _id: -1 } to support reverse order sorts.  Is it not necessary?

Comment: Nope, not necessary because mongodb can use index both ways.

Answer (score 4):

in mongodb3.4, unique and background are not supported in _id field, other fields are possiable.

Answer (score -2):

This error occurred to me also while I was writing test case using sinon.stub to call the functions. ***The cause was***,  I was passing wrong data while stubbing that functions.

**code - ( error code )**

```
const accountstub = sinon.stub(accountservice, "getall");

accountstub.callFake(()=> accountmockdata)
```

**resolved**

```
const accountstub = sinon.stub(accountservice, "getall");

accountstub.callFake(()=> [accountmockdata])
```

**Solution -**
It was expecting an array of objects , and I was passing the object only .
If you use index in your DB, Please be sure I you are passing the right .

You can console the data by running on dev environment and then see what kind of data that functions return (object, array, etc ) and paste the same data in your mock file.

Comment: How this is somehow related with question?